# Unable to import powershell module remotley

Tags: powershell-4.0, remote-desktop, powershell-remoting

I'm importing module remotely. module located in `C:\Users\Ananth\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MSOnline\`. I am able to view the module remotely. while importing getting below error. if try to execute in powershell application module importing successfully in both bit versions.

```
 Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\CAC-Dev\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MSOnline\
1.1.183.66\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
load a program with an incorrect format.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module MSOnline
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageFormatException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand


Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\CAC-Dev\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MSOnline\
1.1.183.66\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll'
```